# How to query a model by a related object and get the related object in the queryset using the Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I know it's possible to query a model using a reverse related field using the Django ORM. But is it possible to also get all the fields of the reverse related model for which the query matched?

For example, if we have the following models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Availability(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

would it be possible to find all `Location`s that are available in a specific timeframe AND also get the `price` of the `Location` during that availability? We are under the assumption that `Availability` objects that have the same location can not have overlapping start/end datetimes.

if `user_start_datetime` and `user_end_datetime` are inputted by the user, then we could possibly do something like the following:

```
Location.objects.filter(
    availability__start_datetime__lte=start_datetime,
    availability__end_datetime__gte=end_datetime)
```

But I'm not sure how to also get the `price` field for the specific `availability` that did result in a match for the query.

In raw SQL, the behavior I'm talking about might be achievable via something like this:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, a.price
FROM Location l
INNER JOIN Availability a
ON a.location_id = l.id
WHERE /* availability is within user-inputted timeframe */
```

I've considered using something like `prefetch_related('availability_set')`, but that would just give me *all* the availabilities for the `Location` objects that matched the query. I just want the *one* `availability` that was within the timeframe that was queried, and more specifically, the `price` of that `availability`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using an ORM, in general you fetch results from one model class at a time. Since `Location` and `Availability` are separate models, you can simply do the following:

```
availabilities = Availability.objects.filter(
    start_datetime__lte=start_datetime,
    end_datetime__gte=end_datetime)
for availability in availabilities:
    print(availability.location.id, availability.location.name, availability.price)
```

Which is an easy to read implementation.

Now, accessing `Location` from an `Availability` object (in `availability.location`) requires a second SQL query. You can optimise this using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

> This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

Simply append it to your original query, i.e.:

```
availabilities = Availability.objects.select_related('location').filter(...
```

This will create an SQL join statement in the background and the `Location` objects will not require an extra query.